# Does the Linux OS run on one core in multi-core system?

Tags: multi-core

If I use a multi-core processor computer, does the Linux OS run on one core or is it distributed to multiple cores? (I know that scheduled processes can be executed on multiple cores.)

Answer (score 2):

Constituent parts of Linux kernel are split out into one or multiple threads (view `ps aux` and look for the processes in square brackets). These threads are scheduled over all available processors and cores.

How Linux-based applications work is really down to how they're written, as is the case on any operating system.